# payable(msg.sender)

Tags: solidity, msg.sender

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Contract {
    address payable public owner;

    constructor() public {
     owner=payable(msg.sender);

    }
    
}
```

msg.sender is of type address by default?

so I  need to explicitly cast it to address payable should I want it to receive funds?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is the case since solidity [v0.8.0](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/080-breaking-changes.html#how-to-update-your-code)

> The global variables tx.origin and msg.sender have the type address
> instead of address payable. One can convert them into address payable
> by using an explicit conversion, i.e., payable(tx.origin) or
> payable(msg.sender).